# Drools 8.44.0.Final: Compare values of two input objects ('facts') in excel decision table? Syntax problem?

Tags: excel, drools

We are using drools as rule framework based on an excel decision table. Lets assume we have two input objects inserted via kieSession:

```
kieSession.insert(car);
kieSession.insert(bike);
```

How can i compare values/properties of those entities/facts in drools excel decision table? We fail fast while defining them in the corresponding cell. How to define them to query them like:

```
$car.getNumberOfWheels() < $bike.getNumberOfWheels()
```

1. Defining them (after importing) like this

```
$car:Car $bike:Bike
```

crashes in "Line 19:24 mismatched input 'bike' in rule "WheelsRule"...

2. Defining them like this

```
$car:Car, $bike:Bike
```

crashes in "Line 19:24 mismatched input ',' in rule "WheelsRule"...

3. Defining them like this

```
$car:Car; $bike:Bike
```

crashes in "Line 19:24 mismatched input ';' in rule "WheelsRule"...

I will add more excel screenshots by time. Any suggestions to define two or more facts in excel for drools? Is it possible at all?

ChatGPT answered my question by spitting out the answer but only as DRL, not for excel.

```
import com.example.Car
import com.example.Bike

rule "Compare Number of Wheels"
when
    $c: Car($numberOfWheelsCar: numberOfWheels)
    $b: Bike($numberOfWheelsBike: numberOfWheels)
    eval($numberOfWheelsCar> $numberOfWheelsBike)
then
    // Your action when the condition is true
    System.out.println("NumberOfWheels from Car is greater than numberOfWheels from Bike");
end

rule "Other Rule"
when
    // Add other conditions or rules as needed
then
    // Your action for other rules
end
```